# Get EditText ID in which Cursor is blinking

Tags: android

I have four edit text. And one button .

First:On Click of button  I want to set the Button  Text to EditText in which cursor is blinking.

Second: After reaching MaxLength  character of Edit text automatically  set  focus to next edit text.

Any Idea  how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of all TextEdit, then search for selected:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isSelected()